# How to design db so that projects have many (invoice/quotes) which many orders

Tags: database-design

Currently, I have DB design where all of the orders belong, to customers, then orders have a lookup table to statuses (invoice/quote/draft).

[image]

I need to redesign it into a form where Customers have projects, each project may have multiple invoices/quotes that are linked to orders. But I am struggling to find out what is the best way to do it.

[image]

Because I work with existing data, I have limits to the number of changes I can do. But I need to be able to get projects from order table, as well as all related orders from invoices or proforma.

What form of relationship I should be creating in such scenario?

The closes that I found was polymorphic relation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations is that the only way I can achieve that or there are more options?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the project have a client (owner) and contractor(s) whereas invoices/orders is linked to customers. Hence you need to reuse the same entity in both roles: owner and customer.

I would suggest to add an entity like "Business party" or even "Legal entity" which may be linked to both "Project clients" and "Customers".